# Oracle sql developer date/month data extract query and syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I Want to extract data from a table for monthwise in oracle sql.
I tried it as follow,
SELECT * From customer ct
Where ct. Application_signed _date in (Date '31-12-2020, Date '01-10-2020')

But i am unable to Fetch the data for this range, whereas data is available for this months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format for a date in Oracle -- and almost everywhere else -- is YYYY-MM-DD:

```
select *
From customer ct 
where ct.Application_signed_date in (Date '2020-12-31, Date '2020-10-01')
```

Note that Oracle dates can have time components.  If that is possible in your data, then one fix is:

```
where trunc(ct.Application_signed_date) in (Date '2020-12-31, Date '2020-10-01')
```

Comment: For getting data from Nov to dec do i have use between or month. What would be the syntax.?

Comment: You would use `>=` and `<`.